# How could I use my defined function as an argument to activate another function?

Tags: python, tkinter, events

What I am trying to do is to set the button status to DISABLED whenever the textbox is empty.
I recreated a snippet of my code bellow:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()

textbox = tkinter.Text(root, height=4)
textbox.pack()

button = tkinter.Button(text="Button", height=2, width=20, state=ACTIVE)
button.pack()


def check_if_textbox_is_empty():
    if textbox.get("1.0", tkinter.END) == "":
        return True


def if_textbox_is_empty():
    button["state"] = DISABLED

# Here is the .bind method I tried, but since it doesn't take func as the first arg it doesn't work for me.
# root.bind(check_if_textbox_is_empty, if_textbox_is_empty)


root.mainloop()
```

How should go about doing this?

What I want to happen is, when my tkinter.Text has no text in it `textbox.get("1.0", tkinter.END) == ""` I want my button widget to be disabled `button["state"] = DISABLED`.
What I have tried is the `.bind` method, but it seems that it only takes tkinter events ex.:`"<Keypress>"` as an argument.

Comment: The statement `if textbox.get("1.0", tkinter.END) == ""` will never be true. If you get all the way to `END` you'll get the final newline that the text widget automatically adds. `textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")` is the standard way to get only the data entered by the user without the trailing newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on correct @JRiggles answer

Only when I added `.strip()` in `if textbox.get("1.0", tkinter.END).strip() == "":` button started change state.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

textbox = tk.Text(root, height=4)
textbox.pack()

button = tk.Button(text="Button", height=2, width=20, state=tk.ACTIVE)
button.pack()


def on_textbox_change(_event=None):
    if textbox.get("1.0", tk.END).strip() == "":
        button["state"] = tk.DISABLED
    else:
        button["state"] = tk.NORMAL


textbox.bind('<KeyRelease>', on_textbox_change)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yees, thanks to you it now definitely works how it's supposed to. On the other hand I have no idea why does this work after adding .strip method..

Comment: @Dronius: it works because the text widget automatically adds a newline at the end. That causes `textbox.get("1.0", END)` to return a single newline if no data has been entered into the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly:
You don't need both

```
import tkinter
```

*and*

```
from tkinter import *
```

Common practice is

```
import tkinter as tk
```

after which you can instantiate widgets like so (note how the constant for the state is *also* prefixed with `tk.` - these constants are, as you may have guessed, part of tkinter)

```
button = tk.Button(text="Button", height=2, width=20, state=tk.ACTIVE)
```

However, just stick with `import tkinter` for now

---

With that out of the way...

Why not simply enable/disable the button within the `if` clause of `check_if_textbox_is_empty()`? You can bind the `'<KeyRelease>'` event to your text box and have it call the check function.

You have several options, all of which will work the same way in the end.

---

###### Option 1

Add an `_event` parameter to the `check_if_textbox_is_empty` function.

The leading underscore `_` is convention to let people know that the value is unused by the function, and `event` is the conventional name for the event argument taken by event-driven functions in tkinter. The default value of `None` isn't strictly necessary, but it's good practice.

```
def check_if_textbox_is_empty(_event = None):
    if textbox.get("1.0", tkinter.END) == "":
        button["state"] = tkinter.DISABLED
    else:
        button["state"] = tkinter.NORMAL


# bind an event handler to your textbox to check it as the user types
textbox.bind('<KeyRelease>', check_if_textbox_is_empty)
```

---

###### Option 2

Use `*_args` in your function to allow it to accept any number of arguments.
Again, the `_` is convention for unused values, and `args` is convention for this type of parameter

```
def check_if_textbox_is_empty(*_args):  # accept any number of arguments
    if textbox.get("1.0", tkinter.END) == "":
        button["state"] = tkinter.DISABLED
    else:
        button["state"] = tkinter.NORMAL


# bind an event handler to your textbox to check it as the user types
textbox.bind('<KeyRelease>', check_if_textbox_is_empty)
```

---

###### Option 3

Use a `lambda` to absorb the event and call `check...` as an anonymous function

```
def check_if_textbox_is_empty():  # no params needed!
    if textbox.get("1.0", tkinter.END) == "":
        button["state"] = tkinter.DISABLED
    else:
        button["state"] = tkinter.NORMAL


# bind an event handler to your textbox to check it as the user types
textbox.bind('<KeyRelease>', lambda _event: check_if_textbox_is_empty())
```

---

###### Bonus Info!

The reason for adding the `_event` parameter (or absorbing it with `*_args` or using a `lambda`) is that tkinter events typically generate an `event` value when triggered, so your code has to be able to accommodate that value.

When you bind a function to an event and that event is triggered, the `event` object gets passed to your function *whether you want it or not!*

There are plenty of reasons you might want your function to use the value of `event`, but for this particular case you don't need it. You can use any of the methods described above to basically throw it out safely.

Comment: It would seem like this should work, but when I add this to the whole code and try this out, using debugger I see that it does go through the function and the if statement, but the if statement returns false even though when I print out the contents of the textbox it returns an empty string, so the if statement should return true. Why would that be the case, or maybe there is a different way to check the contents of the textbox? EDIT: didn't refresh the page and didn't see you edited the comment so I haven't tried the other options you suggested, let me try them out right now.

Comment: You don't need the return statement in `check_if_textbox_is_empty` if you're following my example(s). If you're curious and want to see what your `if` clause is seeing, call `print(textbox.get("1.0", tkinter.END)` just after the `else` branch (and not *inside* the `else` branch)

Comment: p.s (tnx for the tips in answer), Yes, I am not using a return statement and I am printing the textbox contents to see them after the if statement. But this function is not working how it's supossed to since while debugging the if statement it shows that the condition is not True and goes to to the else statement (even though when I print the contents of the textbox it seems like the if statement's condition is supposed to be True).

Comment: Nvm, @Ronin answer solved it. P.s (is there any reason you used <KeyRelease> instead of <KeyPress> in the examples you gave?

Comment: Using `'<KeyRelease>'` prevents issues with key repeats if the key is held down because the event will only trigger when the key is let go